# Easiest way to create multiple nested folders

Tags: finder

For projects, I have to create new sets of folders in finder, sometimes nested to three or four levels, on a regular basis. Currently I copy and paste the previous set and work through each folder deleting its contents until I have a new empty set.

I've seen how you can create folders using a .txt file and terminal, but they are not nested. Is there a quick way to create a 'template' for a specific folder structure I can call up when needed?

Comment: Either create a 'blank' set of folders that you copy; or use a shell script. You should be able to create any sort of hierarchical structure with a script.

Comment: Create a template structure and a tar file from it. Open the tar file at any new place to replicate the structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- create a text file listing all directories to be created and store it in a convenient place

```
foo
foo/bar1
foo/bar2
bar
bar/foo
bar/bar
bar/bar/foo
```

- create the main directory for a new project and `cd` into it
- run `mkdir -p $(< /path/to/textfilefromabove)`

---

For convenience, I would put this into a shell script or function:

```bash
new_project() {
    # new_project [ -t template ] projectdir

    if [ "$1" == "-t" ]; then
        local _template="~/.templates/$2"
        shift 2
    else
        local _template=~/.templates/default
    fi

    if [ ! -r "$_template" ]; then
        echo "Template "$_template not found"
        exit 1
    fi

    mkdir -p "$1"
    cd "$1"
    mkdir -p $(< "$_template")
}
```

PS: Technically, the template file would only need to list the leaf paths, all the intermediate directories would get created automatically.

Comment: Good answer, but I'm sure keeping a spare copy of the empty set would be quicker ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin If you put the command into a `new-project` function which creates the main directory and then populates it? I doubt it :-) But then I have Terminal open anyway.

Comment: I wouldn't like to put a stopwatch on it;)

Comment: @Tetsujin By the time you opened the directory with the template in Finder the shell command has finished :-)

Comment: How about making the template once, and then using a shell script  simply to *copy* it, perhaps also prompting for the root folder's name?

Comment: @BruceVanAllen See edit. Mantaining one (or several) files with the directory structure as text is easier than maintaining directory structures in the file system.

Comment: @nohillside Yes - I was only chiming in re: the speed debate :) Otherwise I like your approach - easy to edit that template file quickly. I would probably allow the CLI input to be either `-t template` or, say, `-n template_name`; the latter would be the name of a template in the ~/.templates dir, alongside ~/.templates/default . For those with multiple standard project setups. Appreciate your shell-fu.

Comment: @BruceVanAllen Actually I wanted `-t` to take the template from `~/.templates`, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the shell's brace expansion to create the folder hierarchy. As an example using nohillside's folder hierarchy-

```
mkdir -p ./{foo/bar{1,2},bar/{foo,bar/foo}}
```

You could stick this in a shell function or create a shell script. One caveat-folder/directory names cannot contain spaces.

Comment: As long as the folder structure is „easy“, this is a great approach.

Comment: You don't need `bar,` since that intermediate directory will be created automatically when creating `bar/foo`.

Comment: Simply use the backslash (the *escape character*) to insert/allow spaces in the folder names: `mkdir -p ./{foo\ foo/bar{1,2},bar/{foo,bar/foo}}` will create the folder `foo foo`, its subfolders and the bar folder and its subfolders. This also works for multiple subfolders: `mkdir -p ./{foo\ foo/bar\ {1,2},bar/{foo,bar/foo}}`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version of @nohillside's shell function above, adapted for Zsh:

```
# make a set of directories
# cd to the directory where projectdir will be created 
# templates in ~/.templates
new_project() {
    # new_project [ -t template ] projectdir
    if [[ ! $1 ]]; then
        echo "Usage: new_project [ -t template ] projectdir"
    else
        if [[ $1 == '-t' ]]; then
            _template=~/.templates/$2
            shift 2
        else
            _template=~/.templates/default
        fi
        if [ ! -r $_template ]; then
            echo "Template $_template not found"
        else
            mkdir -p "$1"
            cd "$1"
            mkdir -p $(< "$_template")
         fi
    fi
}
```

Templates are text files with paths separated by newlines or white space as in @nohillside's example. Paths can go to their end leaves and all intervening directories will be created. Be sure create a template file named 'default'.

I put this function in my .zshrc file.

cd to the directory where `projectdir` will be created, then run the script.

Note that while the created top directory `projectdir` may have spacebar spaces in its name, the subdirectories may not. Suggestions encouraged for how to do that - backslashing a space in a name in a template for this script does not help. `mkdir -p $(< "$_template")` still splits on each space.

Many thanks to @nohillside, the OP, and others who discussed above - I'm pleased to add this to my tools, and thought others might be as well.